# Show that $\Sigma_{j=1}^{n} 1/j(j+1) = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Show that $\Sigma_{j=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{j(j+1)} = \dfrac{n}{n+1}$

I am 
having trouble trying to show this since this series doesnt seem to represent any arithmetic or geometric form of common difference.

Comment: **Hint:** $1=1+j-j$.

Comment: So far we have no use of partial fractions in the class.

Answer (score 0):

a very classic hint: $\dfrac{1}{j(j+1)} = \dfrac{1}{j} - \dfrac{1}{j+1}$. Are you aware of this one ?